# Unable to dynamically reload component

Tags: dynamic, angular

I am trying to dynamically load a tab component based on screen resolution. I have a service with an observable with values: xl, md, sm, xs. The component initially loads on xs and then unloads on screen resizes. The problem is when you resize the screen back to under 768 (xs) the component is not fully materialized. I can see that the component is injected into the DOM on the second load, but it appears the directives are not rendered.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/z7dAcfLBU1GFIDbKGwHq?p=preview) - Try sizing the display full width, then resize back to smallest size to reload tab component

```js
import {Component, bootstrap, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, ComponentRef} from 'angular2/core'
import {UiTabs, UiPane} from './ui_tabs'
import {TabbedLayout} from './tabbed_layout'
import {ResizeSvc} from './resize_svc';  

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div #location></div>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [ResizeSvc]
})
export class App implements OnInit{
  private resizeSvc: ResizeSvc;
  private _children:ComponentRef;
  
  constructor(private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private _e: ElementRef, pResizeSvc:ResizeSvc) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.resizeSvc = pResizeSvc;
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('initialized app.ts');
     
    this.resizeSvc.layout$.subscribe(
        value => this.setLayout(value)
    );
  }
  
  setLayout(pSize:string) {
    this.removeAll();
    
    if(pSize === 'xs') {
      console.log('loading layout ' + pSize);
      //this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(TabbedLayout, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
      this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(TabbedLayout, this._e).then((ref) => {
      ref.instance._ref = ref;
      this._children = ref;
    });
    } else {
      
    }
  }
  
  removeAll() {
    if(this._children != null) {
      console.log('Disposing layout...');
      this._children.dispose();
      this._children = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a picture of the DOM when initially loaded
[image]

And here is a picture of the DOM on the second load with missing tabs
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not letting your CSS take care of this?

Comment: Brad, I'm interested in switching between a card layout for larger resolutions and a tabbed layout for phones. Each tab would contain a single card dynamically loaded. I'm not interested in simply stacking the cards vertically. Ultimately, the "cards" would be resource intensive; so, it is not optimal to simply hide them. I'm all ears if there is a simple CSS solution for this layout requirement. If it helps, each card have animations using createjs. I wouldn't wan't hidden cards, or off screen cards, animating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of `<script>` imports matters. `angular2-polyfills.js` has to be after `system-polyfills.js`. [Here is your plunker working](http://plnkr.co/edit/NvQ7Q5dSiTnBNNDglWbk?p=preview)

I just moved the import below to the top of the list.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdulrahman! Interesting it loaded the first time and not the second.